# VirtualMachineError: revert when calling a stupidly simple Solidity function

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I can't understand why I consistently get the same error when trying to get a value from a simple Solidity function using Python/Brownie, and a local instance of Ganache.

This is the first time I've come across this problem, and I haven't been able to find anything in the forums that can shed some light on me.

Originally, the function was more complex, but I have been simplifying it to find the point where it works, and I have not been able to do it.

This is my silly Solidity function (as I said, is the result of some desperate simplification iterations):

```
    function testFunction(uint256 _value) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 value = _value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

This is my silly call statement with Python:

```
print(Agreement.testFunction(2))
```

And, despite the above newbie code, this is the error I get:

```
File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/GetAgreementData.py", line 18, in main
    print(Agreement.testFunction(2))
  File "brownie/network/multicall.py", line 115, in _proxy_call
    result = ContractCall.__call__(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1902, in __call__
    return self.call(*args, block_identifier=block_identifier, override=override)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1693, in call
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
VirtualMachineError: revert
```

And this is the error I get:

Any help would be very appreciated
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show me your exact and simple smart contract and your minimal python deploy script. Apart from that you can try and use brownie console. Simply open the brownie console, deploy the contract and make the call to your pure smart contract function. Make sure your client is correctly configured for local ganache instance.

Comment: Hi, I can't really explain why, but now it works. I'd love to have some explanation (I've reviewed all the stuff many times, but couldn't really find any logical reason...probably the problem was Ganache misconfiguration or something...). By restarting everything, somehow, it has worked. So there are really no code changes that I can show here. Anyway, thanks for your answer!